# Fine Tuning on Pascal_Voc for specific class

Tags: tensorflow, vgg-net

- I want to fine-tune the vgg19 model for a specific class of pascal VOC dataset? How to do this?
- I am using TensorFlow.
- As data ratio becomes unstable if I use one category vs 19 categories?

Answer (score 0):

Select an appropriate number of negative samples. For example, if you have 100 positive samples, choose 100 negative samples from the other classes and fine-tune your model.